# Step-Up from 12V to 15V using MC34063

Tags: power, inductor, boost, led-driver, mc34063

can someone help me out with using the MC34063 ic, i have a 12V battery and need to have 15V to power 7 LEDs in series (many LEDs altogether).

Ive used a couple of online calculators and an offline one (mc34063 universal calculator) but its not specific.

Is the calculator correct and what values components do i need?

For instance ive found a couple of 39uH inductors but i don't know which ones i need, 2A, 0.8A or 150mA

[Inductors from here](http://www.tme.eu/en/katalog/#id_category=100406&s_field=artykul&s_order=ASC&visible_params=566%2C2%2C568%2C10%2C370%2C38%2C39%2C42%2C2932%2C2931%2C32&used_params=10%3A313%3B566%3A27974%3B)

[image: Calc1]
[image: Sch1]

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation shows that peak current for inductor is Ipeak=1.492A. That means you need inductor that can withstand 1.5A.
So, inductors rated for 0.8A or 150mA are definitely not suitable. Go for 2A one.

Ipeak must be smaller than Isat (saturation current of inductor).